# Angular lazy loading - IE does not render the spinner

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I am trying to show spinner during the lazy loading of Angular modules. (Ng version 5.2)

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
     if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
       this.loading = true;
     } else if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       this.loading = false;
     }
   });
```

Its working in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE 11.
As I see, IE does NOT render anything while modules are being loaded.

Does anyone know how to get it work in IE11 (edited)

Comment: Did you able to see DOM updated in developer tools?

Comment: I would also suggest you to check the css of spinner

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya the spinner component is showing up in the DOM for Chrome but not for IE11 while the modules are being loaded

Comment: @ShashankVivek its not CSS issue as the same CSS is working in IE in other cases.